# Update Index of Threejs BufferGeometry(adding faces)

Tags: typescript, three.js

Adding vertices to a BufferGeometry and updating the positions attribute works fine. But I am starting to get desperate how I can do the same for the index(adding faces). Is there any way how to do this?

```js
const vertices = new Float32Array(100 * 3);
const indices = new Array(100 * 3);
```

These are the arrays that are used.

Update:
This seems to do the trick:

```js
const indices = new Uint16Array(100 * 3);
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
```

Don't know exactly why, but it works.

`geometry.index.needsUpdate = true`
seemed to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

When updating attributes you'd typically use `geometry.setAttribute()`. However, when updating indices you need to use `geometry.setIndex()`, as it's not exactly an attribute per-se. You can read about this method [here in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.setIndex).

For a simple demo on how to use setIndex, you can look at [this live example, and its source code](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=indexed#webgl_buffergeometry_indexed). In essence, you can just pass an array, and the engine will convert it to a `BufferAttribute` for you behind the scenes:

```js
const indices = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0];
geometry.setIndex(indices);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my problem is that I am already using setIndex() when first creating the the mesh. However when I later change my indices array, setIndex() doesn't seem to have any effect.